# Can I use Nautilus to drag and drop files to encrypted folder?

Tags: nautilus, encryption, drag-and-drop

After decades of command line usage I'm getting comfortable using Nautilus (Ubuntu file manager). I'd like to start playing with encryption but do not want to encrypt my whole `/home` directory.

I was thinking of creating a directory of encrypted files and would like to use Nautilus to drag and drop files there.

Can this be done? If so could you outline the steps to accomplish this? Also is it possible to click on an encrypted directory in Nautilus and enter the encryption key to gain access?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at seahorse-nautilus extension? (though may be only context menu implemented

Comment: @doug I have heard of seahorse around here but did not know what it was. Are you suggesting I look at it and answer my own question using seahorse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with encrypted partitions. If you use the disk utility to make a new ext4 partition encrypted with LUKS it will work much how you described however it will show as a drive on the side bar and not a folder.

[image]